# Regex pattern for all words and symbols inside ~{}

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have this input string

```
~{RegExr1234124124.} was ~{created by gskinner.com}, and is ~{proudly hosted} by Media Temple.
```

and want this output:

```
was, and is by Media Template
```

I used `/~{.*}+/g` regex pattern but it is wrong

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Use `str.replace(/~{[^}]+}/g, '')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.*` cause match all characters after `{` in your string.

Use `/~{[^}]+}/` to match every string in `~{}` remove them using `.replace()`

```
var newStr = str.replace(/~{[^}]+}/g, '');
```

```js
var str = "~{RegExr1234124124.} was ~{created by gskinner.com}, and is ~{proudly hosted} by Media Temple.";
console.log(str.replace(/~{[^}]+}/g, '').trim());
```